# Splitting strings and appending to columns based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I am looking at data from an online survey which includes a reason code, reason title and some free text as well as the option to have only free text. The three types of reason could look like this:

1. 01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big
2. Item is too big
3. TOO_BIG

When I split the strings using the following code the free text field for options 2 and three is appended to the first column of the split.

```html
df[['reason_code','reason', 'free_text']] = df['reason_description'].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

| reason_code | reason | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | TOO_BIG | Item is too big |

Comment: Could you show the `head` of your *DataFrame*?

Comment: your code is working as expected, how did you expect the program to know what column it should be in if there isn;t a delim to split by? can you explain your logic some more

Comment: Here is an example of the dataframe    df = pd.DataFrame({'reason_description': ['01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big']})

Comment: @Manakin i would like to append the correct parts to the correct column of the dataframe - not all the columns are delimited into three parts and i want to move the ones that arent into the right column

Comment: @RachelStreater and how would a program know what the correct column is? (this is the key logic missing from your code)

Comment: @manakin I guess I would show that if it’s all caps then it should be the reason, mixture of caps and lowercase then it’s text and if it’s a number it’s the code. Sorry this was missing from my question... I am new to this 

Comment: @RachelStreater okay do you still need help with it, sounds like you've figured out what you need to do

Comment: @Manakin yes I would really love some help if you know how to solve this - I have the logic down but I am struggling to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a *DataFrame* like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'reason_description': ['01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big']})
print(df)
"""
           reason_description
0  01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big
"""
```

Then your code will return this:

```py
df[['reason_code', 'reason', 'text']] = df['reason_description'].str.split('|', expand=True)
print(df)
"""
           reason_description reason_code   reason             text
0  01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big          01  TOO_BIG  Item is too big
"""
```

You can remove the `reason_description` column this way:

```py
col_dict = {
    0: 'reason_code',
    1: 'reason', 
    2: 'free_text'
}

df = df['reason_description'].str.split('|', expand=True).rename(columns=col_dict)
print(df)
"""
  reason_code   reason        free_text
0          01  TOO_BIG  Item is too big
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["A|1|X"],["B|2|Y"]], columns=['reason_description'])
df = df.join(df['reason_description'].str.split("|", expand=True).rename(columns={0:'reason_code',1: 'reason', 2:'free_text'}))
print(df)
```

which would give you

```
  reason_description reason_code reason free_text
0              A|1|X           A      1         X
1              B|2|Y           B      2         Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python dictionaries like so:

```
code = '01|TOO_BIG|Item is too big'  # Our code
# Creating a dictionary with each value corresponding to a None value
r = {
    "reason_code": None,
    "reason": None,
    "text": None,
}

# Assuming each code is split exactly 3 times...
# Splitting our code, and the 0th item will correspond to our 'reason code'
r['reason_code'] = code.split("|")[0]
# Splitting our code, and the 1sh item will correspond to our 'reason'
r['reason'] = code.split("|")[1]
# Splitting our code, and the 2nd item will correspond to our 'text'
r['text'] = code.split("|")[2]
print(r)
'''
You can research more about python dictionaries at:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
'''
```

This is assuming that your code is split between every '|', and will be exactly 3 columns large.

Comment: Some are not three columns and this is the problem, when there are <3 columns the data (usually should be put in the text column) is automatically put in the first column (reason code)